# initialised object causes NPE when accessing a method

Tags: java

in the below code i am tryin to open AVI video with opeCV lib with Java API.
At run time, I receive NPE on the line mentioned below in the code.

why that line causes NPE?

```
public class PlayVideo {

VideoCapture vCapture;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    VideoCapture vCapture = new VideoCapture("C:/private/..../AVIs/parabole.avi");
    boolean mediaOpened = vCapture.open("C:/private/..../AVIs/parabole.avi");

    if (!mediaOpened) {
        System.out.println("media failed to open");
    } else {
        List<Size> prevSizes = vCapture.getSupportedPreviewSizes();//causes NPE

        for (Size s: prevSizes) {
            System.out.println("supportedSize: " + s);
        }

    }
}
```

**Stacktrace**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture.getSupportedPreviewSizes(VideoCapture.java:492)
at openCVJavaExamples.PlayVideo.main(PlayVideo.java:22)
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace. The pointed line can not cause NPE (may be that's inside the method `getSupportedPreviewSizes()`). BTW, you've a local variable with the same name as instance variable. Is that intentional?

Comment: no it wasnt initentional, it was a mistake...the stack trace shows the following: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture.getSupportedPreviewSizes(VideoCapture.java:492)
 at openCVJavaExamples.PlayVideo.main(PlayVideo.java:22)

Comment: What version of the API are you using?  I ask in case this is relevant: http://code.opencv.org/issues/3477

Comment: @FluffmeisterGeneral i am using openCV 2.4.11